# Formatting a table using cfquery and an array

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have written the following query which functions exactly as I have planned:

```
<cfquery name="myquery" datasource="abc">
SELECT DISTINCT Right((Format([vDatum],"yyyy")),2) AS DDate
FROM tVCal RIGHT JOIN tVEvents ON tVCal.VItem = tVEvents.EvDate
</cfquery>
```

Every time this query is run, it outputs a series of two digit year numbers corresponding to years between 1940 and 2039, for which data is available in the database, for example:
00,04,15,28,42,56,58,75,89

Then I have a non-varying list of all year numbers from (19)40 to (20)39 arranged in tabular form, with the first decade looking like this:

```
<tr><td>40</td><td>41</td><td>42</td><td>43</td><td>44</td><td>45</td><td>46</td><td>47</td><td>48</td><td>49</td>       
</tr>
```

Every time this table is displayed and the document is ready, I need a CF or jQuery function which will format all of the year numbers red which were also contained in the output from the original query.

Ten years ago I might have been able to write this myself, but I will be 80 this year and my head swims whenever I try something new. And if I am in the wrong place here, I would be grateful for a hint on where to go.
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<table>
<tr>
<cfloop list = "#YourListOfNumbers#" index = "number">
<cfset ThisColour = ListFind(ValueList(myquery,DDate), number) ? "red" : "black">
    
<td style = "Color:#ThisColour#">#number#</td>
    
</cfloop>
</tr>
</table>
</cfoutput>
```

You'll need to put in some extra work to get more than one row, but that's not part of the question.

A sample of this logic is available here ==> https://trycf.com/gist/dcedc5c1264a4ce18a91ce496a8c0405/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: I just now read your suggestion, Dan, because of the time zone difference here in Europe. Since I have 100 List items, I shall have to decide whether to make an internal loop for the ten table rows or to code all 100 rows discreetly. SO frowns upon using the word "thanks" in comments, so I will just say "danke schön"!

Comment: When I run your code in my page CF says I have no closing tag for <cfscript>. A bald-faced lie, like so many idiotic CF error messages. I will keep hacking away...

Comment: Here is a way to put your 100 numbers into 10 rows.  https://trycf.com/gist/b32727037961d3c2a30bc5c52c8195f6/acf2021?theme=monokai

Comment: That worked nicely for me, I just need to add leading zeroes to the numbers 0 - 9.

Comment: `"...need to add leading zeroes...."` Why not just loop from 1940 to 2039 and format the year number on output? https://trycf.com/gist/08a28ddc8aa8f384ce00eb4d962f6e06/acf2016?theme=monokai `"..no closing tag for <cfscript>..."`  As an aside, there's no benefit to mixing cfscript and cfml syntax in this context. You may find it easier to stick with one style.

Comment: This looks very promising and I will be spending the weekend implementing it. 
Gracias, . . . – – – . . .

Comment: Sounds good.  Note, the example query uses a 4 digit year instead of 2.

Comment: SOS, your code works perfectly using your dummy query, but with my query I am getting the compiler error described elsewhere on SO "Complex constructs are not supported with function ValueList. Use simple variable instead. The CFML compiler was processing:" and my code is: "<cfoutput><cfset eventYears = ValueList(#qYears.DDate#)></cfoutput>".
My host uses CF Version 11. My DB is (sorry) MS Access 2003. My query is shown above, I removed the "RIGHT" function because you took care of that farther down the line. I seem to be so close to a solution!

Comment: It's because of the pound signs #. Normally CF let's you get away with adding extra #'s - even when they're not required - but this function is an exception.   `ValueList()` expects the "name" of the query column. By surrounding it with pound signs #, you're telling CF to evaluate `#qYears.DDate#`, so it ends up passing in a *complex object* (ie. data rows in that column) instead of just its "name". Remove the pound signs and it'll work, i.e. `ValueList(qYears.DDate)`

Comment: (Edit) `"<cfoutput><cfset eventYears = ValueList(#qYears.DDate#)></cfoutput>".`  Also, the CFSET statement doesn't need to be wrapped in a `<cfoutput>` tag. Like the tag name implies, `cfoutput` is only required when outputting - or displaying - the contents of a variable.  Glad it is working now.